# list collect not working when only multiply expression on grails spock test

Tags: groovy, spock, collect

I make test code about list collect

```
import spock.lang.Specification

class CollectTest extends Specification {

  void "test collect"() {
    when:
    def list = [
      [
        name     : 'name1',
        amount   : 1,
        unitPrice: 1000
      ],
      [
        name     : 'name2',
        amount   : 2,
        unitPrice: 2000
      ],
      [
        name     : 'name3',
        amount   : 3,
        unitPrice: 3000
      ]
    ]

    then:
    [1 * 1000, 2 * 2000, 3 * 3000] == list.collect { it.amount * it.unitPrice }
  }
}
```

why did occured error this code, mayby closure has only expression?

this is error console log

Condition failed with Exception:

[1 * 1000, 2 * 2000, 3 * 3000] == list.collect { it.amount * it.unitPrice }
   |         |         |          |
   1000      4000      9000       groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: list for class: com.seojin.api.lang.CollectTest
                                  Possible solutions: class

```
at com.seojin.api.lang.CollectTest.test collect(CollectTest.groovy:28)
```

Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: list for class: com.seojin.api.lang.CollectTest
Possible solutions: class
    ... 1 more

```
then:
[1 * 1000, 2 * 2000, 3 * 3000] == list.collect {
  return it.amount * it.unitPrice
}

then:
[1 * 1000, 2 * 2000, 3 * 3000] == list.collect {
  (it.amount * it.unitPrice) as Long
}
```

work well this code, why?
Why do I need "return"?

Comment: Though your code is well formatted but it's look like unclear what you are asking,Please refer this page for asking good question which usually get upvoted,which helps in getting good answer [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: what's the error ? because I run these tests and all pass. You don't need the return because is implicit in groovy

Comment: @dante2k, the code you've provided is not a pure groovy. it's kind of testing syntax that uses groovy. the closure in groovy always has a `return` statement at last expression even you did not specify it. so problem not in return. please edit your question, and add a tag with name of your test framework. and i guess if you declare a list variable before `when:` the error will disappear.

Comment: Should be tagged [spock]?

Comment: @daggett this error was occurred when test specification on grails.

Comment: @cfrick yes i tested groovy.file what extended grails specification.

Comment: It does not seem to be used as a multiplication operator in spock tests without return keyword.

Answer (score 2):

Spock provides some really nice ways to iterate through data tables. You can rewrite your test like this:

```
def "test collect"() {
    when:
    def result = amount * unitPrice
    then:
    result == expectedResult
    where:
    amount | unitPrice | expectedResult
    1      | 1000      | 1000
    2      | 2000      | 4000
    3      | 3000      | 9000
}
```

This iterates over each row in the table in the `where` and runs the test for the values.

To make the output better, you can add the `@Unroll` annotation, like so:

```
@Unroll("Given I have #amount units with a price of #unitPrice each, then I should have a total amount of #expectedResult")
def "test collect"() {
    when:
    def result = amount * unitPrice
    then:
    result == expectedResult
    where:
    amount | unitPrice | expectedResult
    1      | 1000      | 1000
    2      | 2000      | 4000
    3      | 3000      | 9000
}
```

When you run these tests in an IDE, you will get a different output for each test with a different title.

Worth taking a look at the [spock documentation](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.2/index.html) to see what else this framework can do.

Comment: I'd guess OP does not actually write the list there themself but using the result from the SUT